# How to find the distance form a CLLocationCoordinate2D to a GMSPath?

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to solve a problem: given a CLLocationCoordinate2D (coord) it should be located on, or pretty close(~100m) to a GMSPath(path). How can I find the shortest distance from coord to the path?

Trying compares all coordinates on the path and calculate the distances, then find out the minimum, but it is not a good approach in term of computation cost...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use cordinate+ trigonometry geometry.

If you know the start and end points of the path, you can draw an imaginary line between this points and find a point which is perpendicular from your CLLocationCoordinate2D to this imaginary line.

If your start location is called CLLocationCoordinate2D start, and your end location is CLLocationCoordinate2D end, you first need to find the slope of the equation for this line. This would be ABS(start.latitude - end.latitude) converted into meters and similarly ABS(start.longitude - end.longitude) converted into meters.

Then your slope = (height/width)

Your equation for your imaginary line is y = slope * x - where your imaginary origin is your start location.

Have a look at [this](http://www.wyzant.com/help/math/geometry/lines_and_angles/parallel_and_perpendicular)

Comment: If it is a simple path, this is the solution. But in case it is a curvy S-shape path, just consider the start and end point is not enough. Current solution is compare some sample points on the path, and find out the minimum distance between them and coord.